# doubt about proof of $\int_a^b f + g = \int_a^b f + \int_a^bg$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, proof-explanation

I'm reading calculus by Spivak, I don't understand the last step of the proof. 
Here's the proof (Spivak uses the darboux definition of integral)

> If $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $[a,b]$, then $f+g$ is integrable on [a,b] and $$\int_a^b f + g = \int_a^b f + \int_a^bg$$
>
> Proof:
>
> Let $P = \{t_0, \dots, t_n\}$ be any partition of $[a, b]$ and define 
>   $$m_i = \inf\{(f+g)(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}\\
> m_i' = \inf\{f(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}\\
> m_i'' = \inf\{g(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$$
>
> And define $M_i$,  $M_i'$,  $M_i''$ similarly(same set, but take supremum)
>
> We have $$m_i \geq m_i' + m_i''$$ and
>   $$M_i \leq M_i' + M_i''$$
>
> Therefore $$L(f,p) + L(g,p) \leq L(f+g, p)$$ and $$ U(f,p) + U(g,p) \geq U(f+g, p) $$
>
> thus $$ L(f,p) + L(g,p) \leq L(f+g, p) \leq  U(f+g, p) \leq   U(f,p) + U(g,p) $$
>
> Since $f$ and $g$ are integrable, there are partitions $P'$ and $P''$ with 
>   $$U(f, P') -L(f,P') < \epsilon/2$$
>   $$U(g, P'') -L(g,P'') < \epsilon/2$$
>   If $P$ contains both $P'$ and $P''$, then $$U(f,P) + U(g, P) - [L(f, P) + L(g, P)] < \epsilon $$ and consequently $$U(f+g, P) -L(f+g,P) < \epsilon$$
>
> This proves that $f+g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$(I understand this)
>
> Moreover **(This is the part I don't understand)**
>   $$ L(f,P) + L(g, P) \leq L(f+g, P) \leq \int_a^b f+g 
> \leq  U(f+g, P) \leq U(f,P) + U(g, P)\label{a} \tag{1}$$
>   and 
>   $$ L(f,P) + L(g, P)  \leq \int_a^b f+ \int_a^b g 
> \leq U(f,P) + U(g, P)\label{b} \tag{2}$$
>
> Since $U(f, P) -L(f,P) $  and  $U(g, P) -L(g,P) $  can both be made as small as desired, it follows that $$U(f,P) + U(g, P) - [L(f, P) + L(g, P)] $$ can also be made as small as desired, it therefore follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $$\int_a^b f + g = \int_a^b f + \int_a^bg$$

I don't understand why that proves that $\int_a^b f + g = \int_a^b f + \int_a^bg$, I guess that both $\int_a^b f + g $ and  $\int_a^b f + \int_a^bg$ get squeezed to the same value.

As far as I understand, the way to prove that $\int_a^b f = t $ is to show that $$ \sup\{L(f,P): P \text{  a partition of } [a,b]\} \leq t  \leq \inf\{U(f,P): P \text{  a partition of } [a,b]\} $$

So how does that imply that $$ \sup\{L(f + g,P): P \text{  a partition of } [a,b]\} \leq \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g  \leq \inf\{U(f+g,P): P \text{  a partition of } [a,b]\} $$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, instead of $(1)$, what Spivak proves is that$$L(f,P)+L(g,P)\leqslant L(f+g,P)\leqslant\int_a^bf+g\leqslant U(f+g,P)\leqslant U(f,P)+U(g,P)\tag{1'}$$and, instead of $(2)$, what Spivak proves is that$$L(f,P)+L(g,P)\leqslant\int_a^bf+\int_a^b g\leqslant U(f,P)+U(g,P).\tag{2'}$$So, given $\varepsilon>0$, you take a partition $P$ such that both $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\frac\varepsilon2$ and that $U(g,P)-L(g,P)<\frac\varepsilon2$. So, it follows from $(1')$ and $(2')$ that$$\left\lvert\int_a^bf+g-\left(\int_a^bf+\int_a^b g\right)\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$Since this occurs for each $\varepsilon>0$,$$\int_a^bf+g=\int_a^b f+\int_a^bg.$$

Comment: Thank you. Now it's clear, I think that the author should've included that step, it wasn't obvious to me. Btw (1) and (2) were a typo, I already fixed it :D